# get System configuration fields values - custom module

Tags: magento2, module, system.xml, system-config, system-configuration

I have a module for **Homepage Banner**. I have stated two system config fields inside the module- **etc/adminhtml/system.xml**.

[image]

I need the values of these fields in frontend phtml file `"view/frontend/templates/html/banner.phtml"`.

How will I get these system config fields('enable' and 'banner_content_type') values?

Answer (score 4):

**Recommended way**

```
<?php
namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

get values in phtml

```
$helper = $this->helper('QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Helper\Data');
$helper->getConfig('bannertab/settings/banner_content_type');
$helper->getConfig('bannertab/settings/enable');
```

**Not Recommended way**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('bannertab/settings/banner_content_type');
```